# C - Reversing a sentence - Recursion - Without Array

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, sentence

```
void reverse()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if(c!='\n')
    {
        reverse();
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

When 'c==\n', the program doesn't even get inside the 'if' block. Then how does it print the converted sentence in the end. Please explain where the 'return' happens and also to where it gets returned.

Comment: why don't you read the entire sentence first, reverse it, and then print the entire reversed sentence out.  step 2 and 3 can be merged into one step.  this is simple enough that you don't need to use recursion.

Comment: I'd rather think OP got homework solution but he cant figure out why, hence posting this question. As this probably would not be doing homework for college student I'm more than happy to explain it.

Comment: @thang Recursion is what I'm learning now. So the question is to write the code using recursion. Thanks.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thank you. I don't know how to debug. How do i learn it?

Comment: @optimist: What are you using for development? Visual Studio? Code Blocks? Eclipse? Text editor + terminal?

Comment: @Cornstalks I'm using Geany IDE with GCC compiler in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when 'c==\n', it will be the end of the recursion, the function will not call itself any further and return to the last call, which continues on the line of 'printf("%c", c)', thus printing the last char of the string, then return to the second last call and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Let's run the code by hand. Imagine we input `"foobar"`. We'll right down every instruction the computer processes. If we recurse, we'll just indent as we keep track of things. If we do that, we can see the sequence of instructions executed is:

```
scanf() // reads 'f'
if ('f' != '\n')
  scanf() // reads 'o'
  if ('o' != '\n')
    scanf() // reads 'o'
    if ('o' != '\n')
      scanf() // reads 'b'
      if ('b' != '\n')
        scanf() // reads 'a'
        if ('a' != '\n')
          scanf() // reads 'r'
          if ('r' != '\n')
            scanf() // reads '\n'
            if ('\n' != '\n')
          printf('r')
        print('a')
      print('b')
    print('o')
  print('o')
print('f')
```

Each indentation is a recursive call to `reverse()`. As you can see, the sequence of `printf()` commands are the reverse of the input `"foobar"`.

Hopefully this gives some insights as to how it works.

Comment: That was great! I actually tried doing that way but couldn't figure out when it came to the 'return' part as i said. Sorry if I'm wrong. Is this the debugging you said earlier?

Comment: You can consider this a form of "mental" debugging (where you run the program by hand or in your head). I actually meant using a debugging program on the computer, though, like gdb, lldb, Visual Studio's debugger, etc. These debuggers will let you execute the program on your computer, line by line, and observe what's happening (and why).

Comment: That's great! Do you mind teaching me how to do it? It'll be helpful. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm using Geany IDE with GCC compiler in Ubuntu.

Comment: @optimist: I've never used Geany, so I can't offer any specific advice. But there is a [debugging plugin](http://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html) for Geany. [Here are some docs for it](http://geanydbg.sourceforge.net/walkthrough.htm). The plugin uses gdb under the covers to do the debugging and provides a visual interface for it.

Comment: Thanks for the links. So helpful. Trying it now.